# Statistical Significance between 5 Groups (Percentages)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis, inference

I have 5 samples:

Sample A - size : 10,000, Obesity Rate 5%

Sample B - size : 15,000, Obesity Rate 10%

Sample C - size : 12,000, Obesity Rate 5%

Sample D - size : 9,000, Obesity Rate 6%

Sample E - size : 8,000, , Obesity Rate 7%

What statistical test should be conducted to assert that there is a statistically significant difference amongst the 5 groups. I was thinking Chi-Square.

Would appreciate any inputs.

Comment: What exactly s your $H_0$? That at least 2 groups are different?

Comment: One Way ANOVA might be what you are looking for

Comment: The sample sizes are so large, and the differences in rates so great, that you scarcely need a test to determine there is a difference.  Regardless, what is the matter with the chi-squared test?